# VS Code Error when compiling C++ Program: 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I attempted to follow through on [VS Code's](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) method on making C++ code work on their editor. I did this successfully on my laptop but when I tried compiling it, I was met with the error:

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\salty\Documents\Programming\C++ Scripts\myProgram\main.cpp" -o "C:\Users\salty\Documents\Programming\C++ Scripts\myProgram\main.exe"
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

[This is the entire error message plus extra things in my editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpW74.png)

If I try and copy and paste the command in the message into Windows Power Shell, [it actually works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrztS.png) (New `.exe` file appeared in the correct directory and runs without fault).

[These are my environment variables for `User`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI1oc.png), and [these are my `System` variables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbE8F.png)

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing and changing the paths around. I'm new to C++ programming and how compilers work in general, but I'm not sure why VS Studio says it doesn't recognize `cmd` among others it could've not recognized.

Why is it giving me this error?

**Edit:** I believe I didn't include a `return 0;` line in the program. Correcting this did not fix the issue.

Comment: *C++ Scripts* C++ is not a scripting language.

Comment: Silly question, have you restarted VSCode?

Comment: @273k I didn't, but I also fixed the issue, and I can't seem to replicate it again. I am very, *very* confused.

Comment: Nice, good luck in moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what I poked into place or if I just was too incompetent to realize something, however adding `%SystemRoot%\system32` to my `PSModulePath` environment variables somehow fixed the issue, and since that action I have yet to replicate the compile error.

I don't know if adding that variable to my environments permanently fixed it or VS Studio needed a moment to process some things. Thanks anyways!